# Unable to connect to the internet Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I recently installed Ubuntu. After installing, it updated all the software through Ubuntu software.
Since then, I am unable to connect to the internet. The machine picks up wifi and is able to connect to wifi, but no internet. I have tried:

- Ping a known host([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) using `ping www.google.com`
- Pink a known ip address(googles dns 8.8.8.8 for example)
- Connect the machine to the router via a working ethernet cable.
- Checking the status of the firewall(it is inactive `sudo ufw status` returns `Status:inactive`)

None of the above works. The content of `/etc/resolv.conf` is the same as on another laptop running the same version of ubuntu:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

I have seen suggestions to modify the nameserver but the fact that I cannot even ping known public IP addresses leads me to believe that is not the issue here. Since wired does not work, I don't think it is the wifi driver.

Does anyone have any ideas or has run into something similar?

**Edit**

the output of `sudo lshw -C network` is different between my machine and another that has working internet. In the machine that works, there is only:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 96
   serial: 8c:70:5a:83:b5:34
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 6000g2a-6.ucode ip=192.168.1.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:26 memory:f0c00000-f0c01fff
```

Whereas in the one that does not work, I the output has 2 lines. One is Ethernet interface and the other is Wireless interface(very similar to the one above, except the ip address is 192.168.1.25)
I guess there are 2 because the broken machine has a ethernet port but the one working does not.

Comment: could you add the output of `ip addr` ?